# How to add page no. and print date ms interop word DLL

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to add following text into MS-Word footer using MS-Interop Word DLL.

Required Footer Text:

"Page 1 of 10 and date = {Current Date}" something like this.
I have added below code which add page no. and current date but its not allowing me add any custom text like "Page 1 of 10".

Here is my code

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section wordSection in document.Sections)
            {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
        footerRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);


        footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldDate,"Date = ");
        footerRange.Fields.UpdateSource();
        footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage, "Page No = ");
        footerRange.Fields.UpdateSource();


        footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;


    }
```

An idea how to add such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which I have found.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section wordSection in document.Sections)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                    footerRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);


                    footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph p4 = footerRange.Paragraphs.Add();
                    p4.Range.Text = " of ";
                    footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

                    footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph p1 = footerRange.Paragraphs.Add();
                    p1.Range.Text = "Page: ";
                    footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph p3 = footerRange.Paragraphs.Add();
                    p3.Range.Text = " " + Environment.NewLine;

                    footerRange.Fields.Add(footerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldDate);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph p2 = footerRange.Paragraphs.Add();
                    p2.Range.Text = "Print date: ";

                    footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
                }
```